# BigQuery: How to iterate through list and use variable in where clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table called `t1` and I want to count distinct values for an `id` column based on a list of known values in that exist in column `ìd2`.

How can I do this iteratively in BigQuery?

To do this kind of query one at a time, I would do

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM t1 WHERE id2 = '113'`

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM t1 WHERE id2 = '50'`

When I try this for multiple values for `id2`:
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM t1 WHERE id2 IN ('113', '50')`

it counts all of the values in the list. ie. unique `ìd` for '113' + '50'

How do I execute a query that will iterate through a list of `ìd2` values?

Comment: why dou you want to iterate, to get the counts of every number?

Comment: The idea is to run one query that will allow me to find counts for several numbers, rather doing doing a query for each number, since I have over 50 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select id2, count(distinct id)
from t1
join unnest([113, 50]) id2
using(id2)
group by id2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, id2, COUNT(1)
FROM t1
GROUP BY
id, id2
```

This will return a list of:

| id | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 3 |

etc...

Which will contain all of the unique pairings of id and id2, from here you should be able to extract what you need.

From here you should be able select the values that you want i.e. as in above example:

```
SELECT * FROM previous_results
WHERE id2 IN ('113', '50')
```